# Can I force router changes from linux CLI, like port forwarding with UPNP?

Tags: linux, router, lan, upnp

I have seen that I can use miniupnp to apply port forwarding on my router, and I would like to find another tool to apply DNS and/or DHCP settings on the router. Is this possible?

My goal is to have a script that once executed, it configures a VPN and DNS on my server, and also configures the router accordingly ( VPN port forward and DNS pointing to my LAN server ) without any user intervention.

Thank you for your help!

**Edit::**

I have found an interesting [python tool](https://upnpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that can help me discover UPNP devices on my network and also the UPNP services they provide. I have also understood that I need [theLANHostConfigManagement](http://upnp.org/specs/gw/UPnP-gw-LANHostConfigManagement-v1-Service.pdf) UPNP service in order to modify DNS and DHCP settings on the router.

Unfortunately neither of my 3 router devices provide this service, and for obvious reasons. I have understood the risks to allow for such devices for an app to change such settings.

But then is there another way how/work around to achieve this convenience?

My goal is to have a Raspberry Pi running PiHole or AdGuard Home (DNS) and that can be easily installed in a home network. Is there a creative mind that think of and show me of a way to automate DNS configuration without having the user do it himself, while keeping it safe and local?

Comment: why are you assuming that all routers are the same?

Comment: I haven't mentioned that at all. I'm interested in routers that can make use of UPNP

Comment: Enterprise routers can often be accessed with SSH, and have quite advanced (vendor-specific) command languages: these could be scripted fairly easily. Some (but not all) home/small-business routers might have something similar, but possibly with reduced functionality and almost always hidden deep in the "advanced" section of the router documentation if this feature exists at all. Without knowing the make and model of your router, it will be impossible to give any specific advice.

Comment: @telcoM thank you for your insights, this is very interesting and I'm checking about it. I haven't mentioned my router model because I don't want to be limited to only one model, I would like to find a solution which at least hits most models.

Comment: SSH doesn't seem like the way to go for me. I'm using an Arris cable modem, provided by my ISP company, very low end gateway. Anyhow my goal is to manage DNS settings for most modem/router devices, if it is possible at all

Comment: If it was possible to change DNS or DHCP settings of a router (even from the local network only) without any kind of authentication, that would be a serious security weakness: someone (or a malware-infected host) could change DNS settings to route all DNS queries of the router's clients to itself or to some other evil DNS server, or change DHCP default gateway settings to route all outgoing traffic through the evil/infected host. Either of those would enable a number of further attacks against other hosts connected to that router. "And that's why we can't have nice things."

Comment: that's a very good point. Still though, all these settings are protected just by the routers web interface, so why not offer a way to allow the user to provide permissions for such apps? :)))